# How to add a Environment Scope and Deployment Target Scope to a variable in OctopusDeploy

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopus

I have to generate a variable dynamically and set it to the variable list using Octopus Deploy REST API.

I don't know how to set the Environment Scope and Deployment Scope to that variable for different values.

Example - ENV_NAME -> [dev,sit,uat,prod - are values for ENV scope (dev,sit,uat,prod) and roles (x,y,z)] etc

How to set the corresponding values for each scope using Octopus REST API

Below is what I have to set the variable name and values

```
$variableList = @(
  @{
     Name = "API_ID"
     Value = $api_id
     Type = "String"
     IsSensitive = $false 
  }
)

# Get space
$space = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "$octopusURL/api/spaces/all" -Headers $header) | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $spaceName}

# Get project
$project = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "$octopusURL/api/$($space.Id)/projects/all" -Headers $header) | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $projectName}

# Get project variables
$projectVariables = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "$octopusURL/api/$($space.Id)/variables/$($project.VariableSetId)" -Headers $header

foreach($variable in $variableList){
  # Check to see if variable is already present
  $variableToUpdate = $projectVariables.Variables | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $variable.Name}
  if ($null -eq $variableToUpdate)
  {
     # Create new object
     $variableToUpdate = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
     $variableToUpdate | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $variable.Name
     $variableToUpdate | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Value" -Value $variable.Value
     $variableToUpdate | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Type" -Value $variable.Type
     $variableToUpdate | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "IsSensitive" -Value $variable.IsSensitive

     # Add to collection
     $projectVariables.Variables += $variableToUpdate

     $projectVariables.Variables
  }

   # Update the value
   $variableToUpdate.Value = $variable.Value
}   

# Update the collection
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri "$octopusURL/api/$($space.Id)/variables/$($project.VariableSetId)" -Headers $header -Body ($projectVariables | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [OctopusDeploy-Api](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api) repo contains many sample scripts.

[ModifyOrAddVariableToProject.ps1](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api/blob/master/REST/PowerShell/Variables/ModifyOrAddVariableToProject.ps1) does almost exactly what you are attempting to do here.

Two things to note, environment scopes have to be the Id of the environment, not the name as shown [here](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api/blob/01b308d95894d735e5b319ecd4d94b18e8f3ce40/REST/PowerShell/Variables/ModifyOrAddVariableToProject.ps1#L33), but roles can just be any string, under the scope type of `Roles`.

If you are trying to scope a variable to the deployment process, then the scope type is `ProcessOwner` and the value would be the Project Id, or to scope to a runbook it would be the Runbook Id.